# ADO: Able to use pipeline variables in a query?

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to have a gate which requires at least one work item of the 'Release' type associated with the pipeline. Is there a way to have the gate query execute `SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.WorkItemType] = 'Release' AND [Com.Pipeline] = "$(Release.DefinitionName)"` (or equivalent)?

I need it to work through multiple pipelines, which is why I would like to use on of the built-in variables to avoid creating a hundred separate queries. If not possible, is there a better way to stop deployment from moving to the next stage if there isn't a specific associated work item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ended up reading about the WIQL API calls, and used an 'Invoke Web Request' task to execute the above query, with the success criteria being `root['workItems'][0]`, which errors out if there isn't an element present. Not quite as elegant as the Query task I was shooting for, but it serves its purpose.